# RecyclerView notifyDataset Changed issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having problem in the View during notifyDataSetChanged in recyclerView. I implemented pull torefresh logic. So I refresh my RecyclerView and call notifyDataSetChanged. I create a linear layout dynamically and add it to the parent view. The Dynamic linear layout has images. It displays correctly when it loads initially. During pull to refresh, the images loads but disappears immediately. I couldnot understand what the problem would be?

Part of BindViewHolder

```
if(tempAvailable == true && heartAvailable == true && lungAvailable == true) {
    for(i in 1..3) {
        if(i == 1) {
            val df = DecimalFormat("#.##");
            var childLinearLayout:LinearLayout? = createChildView(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.temperature), df.format(coreBodyTemp).toString(), context.getString(R.string.temperatureStr))
            parentLinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout)
            //childLinearLayout = null
        } else if(i == 2) {
            var childLinearLayout:LinearLayout? = createChildView(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heart), heartRate.toString(), context.getString(R.string.heartRate))
            parentLinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout)
            //childLinearLayout = null
        } else if(i == 3) {
            var childLinearLayout:LinearLayout? = createChildView(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.lung), "", "")
            parentLinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout)
           // childLinearLayout = null
        }
    }
} else if (tempAvailable) {
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.##");
    var childLinearLayout:LinearLayout? = createChildView(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.temperature), df.format(coreBodyTemp).toString()+" \u00B0F", context.getString(R.string.temperatureStr))
    parentLinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout)
    //childLinearLayout = null
} else if (heartAvailable) {
    var childLinearLayout:LinearLayout? = createChildView(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heart), heartRate.toString()+" bpm", context.getString(R.string.heartRate))
    parentLinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout)
   // childLinearLayout = null
} else if (lungAvailable) {
    var childLinearLayout:LinearLayout? = createChildView(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.lung), "", "")
    parentLinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout)
    //childLinearLayout = null
}
```

The method which creates linear layout dynamically

```
fun createChildView(icon: Bitmap,readingVal: String, readingTag: String) : LinearLayout {
    val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    lp.weight = 1f
    val parent: LinearLayout = LinearLayout(context)
    parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)
    parent.setLayoutParams(lp)

    val imageView = ImageView(context)
    val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    layoutParams.weight = 0.4f
    layoutParams.height = 60
    layoutParams.width = 60
    layoutParams.leftMargin = 10
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 10
    layoutParams.topMargin = 10
    layoutParams.bottomMargin =10

    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
    imageView.setImageBitmap(icon)
    parent.addView(imageView)


    val readingLayout = LinearLayout(context)
    readingLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)
    val lp1 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    lp1.weight = 0.6f
    lp1.topMargin = 10
    readingLayout.setLayoutParams(lp)

    val displayValue = TextView(context)
    val layoutParams1 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0)
    layoutParams1.weight = 0.7f
    layoutParams1.topMargin = 24
    layoutParams1.bottomMargin = 4
    displayValue.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1)
    displayValue.setText(readingVal)
    displayValue.setTextSize(12f)
    displayValue.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    readingLayout.addView(displayValue)

    val displayTag = TextView(context)
    layoutParams1.weight = 0.3f
    layoutParams1.topMargin = 0
    displayTag.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1)
    displayTag.setText(readingTag)
    displayTag.setTextSize(8f)
    displayTag.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    displayTag.setAlpha(0.6f)
    readingLayout.addView(displayTag)
    parent.addView(readingLayout)

    return parent
}
```

UPDATE:

I fixed this issue by putting setHasStableIds(true) in Recycler view constructor

Answer (score 0):

From Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#setHasStableIds(boolean)),

### setHasStableIds

void setHasStableIds (boolean hasStableIds)

> Indicates whether each item in the data set can be represented with a
> unique identifier of type Long.

You must set `setHasStableIds(true)` for your recycle view